# Look for a counterexample about convergence in measure

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for a counterexample for the following asserting: Let $f_n$ be a sequence of measurable functions on a measurable set $E$ convergent in measure to $f$. Then $\{f^2_n\}$ converges in measure to $f^2$.

$f_n$ in all known counterexamples are not finite a.e, so my question is whether there is one counterexample so that $f_n$ are all finite a.e.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Do you mean not *finite* a.e. or not *bounded* a.e.? (Maybe give one of the counterexamples you already recognize.)

Comment: Yes. you are right. I meant looking for bounded functions $f_n$.

Answer (score 2):

$x+1/n$ converges to $x$ uniformly on $(0,\infty),$ hence in measure, but $m(\{(x+1/n)^2 - x^2 > 1\} = \infty$ for all $n.$

Comment: Thanks for help. But what I really want to ask is a counterexample such that all $f_n$ are bounded, since the counterexamples I have known are not bounded, as the one given above by zhw.